# Can't save image in phpMyAdmin database, getting [BLOB - 0 B]

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I'm trying to upload image and save it in my sql database. 
I tried upload several images, but every time i'm getting [BLOB - 0 B]. 
I checked file_uploads=On in php.ini

This is my code:
regklub.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="regklub.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Logo: <input type="file" name="logo"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    define('DB_NAME', 'lala');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER,);
    if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

    $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["logo"]["name"]);
    $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"]));

    echo $imageData;


}
?>

</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is **not** a database. nothing in your code inserts anything in to any db

Comment: Nor does anything in the code shown handle file uploads.  We need minimum viable example code. Also you may seriously want to reconsider storing images in DB. In most cases this us a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

one example for you

one example

```
$erroimagem= "";
$extensoes['extensoes'] = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'JPG', 'JPEG');
$imagem = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']));
$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['imagem']['name'])));

    if (array_search($extensao, $extensoes['extensoes']) === false) {
        $erroimagem = "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png";
    } elseif ($_FILES['imagem']['size'] > 1000000) {
        $erroimagem = "O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até 2Mb.";
    }

    if(empty($erroimagem)) {

    $query = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO utilizadores(imagem) VALUES ('$imagem', now())") or die (mysql_error());

    }
```

Comment: Why this :"echo $imageData; " part of code doesn't work? I don't get these signs for picture like in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPGxWaIhLmk (5:25)